# argparse without dash argument (just input source filepath)

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

### Question:

Is it possible to execute: **test_argparse.py c:\folder\somefile.txt** and get

print results: **Namespace(filepath='c:\\folder\\somefile.txt')**

Adding *-filepath* is not a big deal, but just wondering if there is some way to skip it if you only need to pass in a filepath.

### Working Code:

filename: **test_argparse.py**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-filepath', metavar='in-file')
results = parser.parse_args()

print results
```

execute: **test_argparse.py -filepath c:\folder\somefile.txt**

print results: **Namespace(filepath='c:\\folder\\somefile.txt')**

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a `positional` argument.  You specify the argument name, in this case, `filepath`, but without any prefix (-).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filepath', metavar='in-file')

results = parser.parse_args('test'.split())
# Namespace(filepath='test')
results = parser.parse_args()
print results
```